# Batch file scripting issue

Tags: batch-file

I am performing a certain operation on a number of files and following is the bat file script written for it. 
names of the files are of this type: aspen_1M_bursty_25_1.pcap

```
@FOR /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   @%decoder% -i L:\martin\05_distorted\Elecard\%~n1_bursty_25_%%i.pcap -o L:\martin\05_distorted\Elecard\%~n1_bursty_25_%%i.avi
)
```

Th problem is, this script adds '-' inside and ends up calling the command like the following:

```
-i L:\martin\05_distorted\Elecard\-_bursty_25_1.pcap -o L:\martin\05_distorted\Elecard\-_bursty_25_1.avi 
                                  ^                                                    ^
```

Hence it would return an error that there is no such file as the names of the files have no '-' in them:

The above script is in a bat file and I am calling the bat file through command prompt.

How to get rid of this '-' thing? :)

Comment: How are you running the script? Please show the full commandline.

Comment: The output redirection operator is `>`, not `->`. Use `name.bat aspen_1M >log.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `%~n1` substitution parameter. Read `HELP CALL` to understand how this works.

In your case, `%1` is the first parameter passed to your code.

So you need to review the way you invoke this code.

If this a :label being CALLed, then review the `CALL` command.

If it is in the main BAT script, then review the way you invoke the BAT from the command line, or from another BAT.

It seems that you are passing **"-"**.

```
name.bat ->log.txt
```

If you, instead, pass **"aspen"**  it should work correctly. This way:

```
name.bat aspen >log.txt
```

Comment: sorry, but the answer solves your problem. You are actually passing a "-" parameter. So, instead of ***name.bat ->log.txt*** invoke it as **name aspen >log.txt**